# How to check if required fields are filled including upload file before submit?

Tags: php, html

this code has no error but when i upload file with some/all empty fields , files gets uploaded. but when it doesnot check the other fields are empty or not. is there something missing in my code?
how can i check if all required fields are filled ?

**form.php**

```
<form action="uploadform.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <br><br> 
Image Title:  <input type="text"    name="imagetitle"  ><br><br>
              <input type="hidden"  name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="2000000">
              <input type="file"    name="userfile"  id="userfile" ><br><br>
Choose Date:  <input type="date"    name="pickdate" > <br><br>
<input id="button_1" type="radio" name="option"  value="button1" /><label for="button_1" >Button 1</label>
<input id="button_2" type="radio" name="option"  value="button2" /><label for="button_2" >Button 2</label><br><br>
<select name="list1"> 
      <option value="">Select Options</option>
      <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="option2">Option 2</option> 
      <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<select name="list2"> 
      <option value="">Select Type</option>
      <option value="type1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="type2">Option 2</option> 
      <option value="type3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<br><br>
        <input name="upload" type="submit" class="box" onclick="return validateForm()" id="upload" value=" Upload " >
</form>
```

**formhander.php**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['upload']))



  if ($_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0) {
{
echo '<pre>'; 
print_r($_POST); 
echo '</pre>';
}
$allowed_filetypes = array(
      '.jpg',
      '.jpeg',
      '.png',
      '.gif'
    );
$requiredFields = array(
  'imagetitle',
  'pickdate',
  'option',
  'list1',
  'list2',
);
$errors = array();
foreach($_POST AS $key => $value)
{
    // is this a required field?
    if(in_array($key, $requiredFields) && $value == '') 
     $errors[] = "The field $key is required.";
}
    $max_filesize      = 1445760;
    $description       = $_POST['imagetitle'];
    $filename          = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $ext               = substr($filename, strpos($filename, '.'), strlen($filename) - 1);
    if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_filetypes))
      die('The file you attempted to upload is not allowed.');
    if (filesize($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize)
      die('The file you attempted to upload is too large.');
    $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $tmpName  = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['userfile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['userfile']['type'];
    $date= $_POST['pickdate'];
    $fp       = fopen($tmpName, 'r');
    $content  = fread($fp, filesize($tmpName));
    $content  = addslashes($content);
    fclose($fp);
    if (!get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
      $fileName = addslashes($fileName);
    } //!get_magic_quotes_gpc()
    include 'config.php';
    include 'opendb.php';
    $query = "INSERT INTO upload (column1,column2,column3,column4,column5,column6,) " . "VALUES ('$fileName', '$fileSize', '$fileType', '$content', '$date','$description')";
    mysql_query($query) or die('Error, query failed');
    include 'closedb.php';
    echo "<br>File $fileName uploaded<br>";
  } //isset($_POST['upload']) && $_FILES['userfile']['size'] > 0
  else {
    echo 'Please Upload an Image.';
  } //isset($_POST['upload'])

header('Location: form.php');
exit; 

?>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With HTML5 you can now check to see if fields are filled or not without PHP. Simply add `required=""` inside your `<input ... />` tag and if they are not filled a message will pop up telling the user that the field is required.

**EDIT**

This solution only helps the client, like Mike said in the comments. It is very unsecure if you only use this for 'validation'.

Comment: thnx dude for the help, up rep. Problem sovled

Comment: HTML5 validates on the client. It's a user convenience, nothing more. There's nothing to stop someone malicious creating a malformed `POST` and attempting to hack your site with it. Your server should always validate **everything** it receives.

Comment: Mike is correct. This solution is just for the client. If you are going to use this, use this along with server-side validation. Meda gave an answer that gave an example.

Answer (score 2):

Check like this

```
if (isset($_POST['upload']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']) )
```